# Clickable button within bootstrap list-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list-group with list-group-items in it in the form of buttons. I would like to add clickable icons to each list-group-item, for example delete buttons. However, when adding an icon to a list-group-item I can either prepend the icon to the list-group-item or place it before the item. When I prepend the icon, it comes out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8dIi.jpg). Clicking the delete icon triggers the click event for the entire list-group-item, not the click event for the delete icon.

Javascript where I add the list-group-items and the delete icon(button):

```
var button = $('<button/>').text(result[key].deviceId).addClass('list-group-item device').attr({name:result[key].deviceId, "aria-label": "Quick View Device", "data-toggle": "modal", "data-target": "#quick-view-device-modal", type: "button"});
var deviceName = result[key].deviceId;
var deleteButton = $('<button/>').attr('type','button').attr('name','delete').attr('id',deviceName).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign red"></span>').addClass('icon delete-device');
button.prepend(deleteButton);
$('#device-list').append(button);
```

This code ends up adding the delete icon button within the list-group-item button, as a child element. I believe that is why clicking the delete icon button triggers the click event for the entire list-group-item. Because of this, I tried another way:

Javascript for adding delete icon before list-group-item:

```
var button = $('<button/>').text(result[key].deviceId).addClass('list-group-item device').attr({name:result[key].deviceId, "aria-label": "Quick View Device", "data-toggle": "modal", "data-target": "#quick-view-device-modal", type: "button"});
var deviceName = result[key].deviceId;
var deleteButton = $('<button/>').attr('type','button').attr('name','delete').attr('id',deviceName).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign red"></span>').addClass('icon delete-device');
$('#device-list').append(button);
$('button[name='+deviceName+']').before(deleteButton);
$('.delete-device').hide();
```

When I add the icon before each list-group-item, it comes out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXiOu.png). The icon does nothing when I click it.
First of all, if I add the delete icon like this how would I make the icon line up with the item it corresponds with? Secondly, why is the click event for the icon not being triggered when I click it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a  `click` event listener to your `#device-list` element and delegate the event to the button element. Inside the event handler callback check if the event target is the `span` or the `button`.

Here is an example, kind of trying to mimic the code you have in your question.

```js
var result = {
  one: { deviceId: "dummy_one" },
  two: { deviceId: "dummy_two" },
  three: { deviceId: "dummy_three" }
}

var $deviceList = $('#device-list');
var $modal = $('#quick-view-device-modal');
var modalShowHndl = function (evt) {
  var button = evt.data.relatedTarget;
  $(this).find('.modal-title').html(button.text())
  $(this).find('.modal-body').html('<p>' + button.text() + '</p>')
}
var $relatedTarget;

for (var key in result) {
  var deviceName = result[key].deviceId;
  var button = $('<button/>')
  .text(' ' + deviceName)
  .addClass('list-group-item device')
  .attr({name:deviceName,
         "aria-label": "Quick View Device",
         "data-toggle": "modal",
         type: "button"});

  var deleteButton = $('<span/>')
  .attr({
    name: 'delete',
    id: deviceName
  })
  .addClass('icon delete-device glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign red');

  button.prepend(deleteButton);
  $deviceList.append(button);
}

$deviceList.on('click', 'button', function(evt) {
  if($(evt.target).hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
    console.log('delete device:',evt.target.parentNode.textContent)
  } else {
    $relatedTarget = $(evt.target);
    $modal.one('show.bs.modal', {relatedTarget: $relatedTarget}, modalShowHndl)
    $modal.modal('show')
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" id="device-list"></ul>

<div id="quick-view-device-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! However one problem, when I click the delete icon the click handler runs twice. I thought I'd fix this by disabling the button after I click it, anyone have a better fix for that?

Comment: You mean in my example ? Can't seem to see that. Maybe it is because when you create the `deleteButton` in you `for` loop you are using a `var deleteButton = $('<button/>')`, which is another button. I am creating the `span` element directly. Take a look at the `for` loop in my example.

Comment: Just noticed that, changed it to just a span like yours. Now the click event isn't triggered twice, but the handlers for both the delete button and the list-group-item run. So after the delete icon handler, the modal pops up.